# ssh and monitor attached on the server

Tags: ssh

can you please give some advise on a little problem that I'm facing, and maybe some confusion to?
I have a file/web server that I use to play with it, and it does not have a graphical desk top, after it boots it stays on a terminal mode waiting for commands.
i use ssh (putty) to login on the server from my desktop PC.
What i wanted to ask, is it possible to have all the commands that I'm typing on the ssh appear on the monitor that is connect on the server?
I searched to web trying to find something about that, but was unsuccessful, can you please give me some ideas?
i found a option to forward a session by using the option -X on ssh, but to use that would i have to have the x server installed on my server?
and if I do install it, would it make the server have a graphical desktop? I don't want to have the server to be graphical, I like it in terminal mode.
thank you.

Comment: Do you have keyboard attached to the server?

Answer (score 1):

You can go with "tmux" (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html)

You can start a shared session with `tmux new-session -s session_name` and in a the other Terminal you can attach to the session with `tmux attach-session -t session_name`